# How to group elements of nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

There is an array:

```
var ind = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
```

And another array:

```
var arr = [
  ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana"],
  [ 11,      12,       34,     54,     76,      23,      232    ],
  [ 33,      54,       22,     11,     23,      21,      33     ]
];
```

How to combine all the values of the subarrays in order, as they go in the array ind, to make it like this:

```
var arr = [
  [ "Apple",      "Pear",   "Banana"  ],
  [  [11, 76, 23], [34, 54], [12, 232]],
  [  [33, 23, 21], [22, 11], [54, 33] ]
];
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the number groupoing?

Comment: @AndreaFacchini seems like it's more or less a "table". Everything in an "Apple" column would be compressed into one. I think - I changed the formatting so I (and others) can see it more clearly.

Comment: Split off the first row, then loop through the array and check into which array the column should go. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Combine into subarrays numbers that match the indices with ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"]

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: My code didn't work, but I already got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `reduce` and `forEach` methods to create new array and add sub-arrays based on `indexOf` current element from the first row and index of the same element in `ind` array.

```js
var ind = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
var arr = [
  ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana"],
  [11, 12, 34, 54, 76, 23, 232],
  [33, 54, 22, 11, 23, 21, 33]
];
const first = arr[0];

const result = arr.slice(1).reduce((r, e, i) => {
  const a = r[i + 1] = [];

  e.forEach((el, j) => {
    const index = ind.indexOf(first[j])
    if (!a[index]) a[index] = [el];
    else a[index].push(el)
  })

  return r;
}, [ind])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array as helper for getting the right index and reduce the array by taking the index and collect the values to the index.

```js
var columns = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"],
    data = [["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana"], [11, 12, 34, 54, 76, 23, 232], [33, 54, 22, 11, 23, 21, 33]],
    indices = data[0].map(v => columns.indexOf(v)),
    result = [columns, ...data.slice(1).map(a => a.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        (r[indices[i]] = r[indices[i]] || []).push(v);
        return r;
    }, []))];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` to merge the values into one depending on the index of head

```js
var ind = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];
var [head, ...rest] = [
  ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Pear", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana"],
  [ 11,      12,       34,     54,     76,      23,      232    ],
  [ 33,      54,       22,     11,     23,      21,      33     ]
];

let out = [ind, ...rest.map(row => Object.values(row.reduce((acc, curr, i) => (acc[head[i]].push(curr), acc), ind.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = [], acc), {}))))];

console.log(out)
```